# Why my codeigniter phpunit does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpunit

I update my codeigniter framework from 2.1.3 to 3.0.0,now the problem is my old phpunit not work.

BTW the development environment:

```
phpunit version: PHPUnit 4.7.6
php versioin: PHP 5.5.25
```

When I run mysql phpunit testcase, it tell me that:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getMessage() on a non-object 
in /framework/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/system/core/Common.php on line 653
```

The code of phpunit_bootstrap.php is blowed:

```
/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 * Define a custom error handler so we can log PHP errors
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
//set_error_handler('_exception_handler');
$BM =& load_class('Benchmark', 'core');
```

As the above code , now I get the `//set_error_handler('_exception_handler');` cause the problem.But I always don't know why.

Comment: Add your code related to your Question

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear. What object are you calling getMessage from?

Comment: Common.php on line 653 is a part of Exception Handler. It is strange non-object is passed to it.